# How do you convert the μmol/mol units for atmospheric CO2 into CO2 mass fraction?

Tags: atmosphere, climatology, carbon

The Keeling curve reports CO<sub>2</sub> in units of μmol/mol, but people's (and country's) emissions are generally reported in kilograms or tons of CO<sub>2</sub>. I would like to convert μmol/mol of CO<sub>2</sub> in the atmosphere to mass fraction of CO<sub>2</sub> in the atmosphere using an accurate, well-established, and scientifically accepted method to ensure that my calculations are reproducible by others. What is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: A somewhat connected, albeit different, question: [Ppmv vs μmol for atmospheric CO2](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10157/ppmv-versus-μmol-mol-for-atmospheric-co2-how-to-convert/10367)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Multiply $\ce{CO_2}$ expressed in μmol/mol by 1.52 the μg/g equivalent.

Details: The molecular mass of $\ce{CO_2}$ is 44.01 g/mol. The standard molecular mass of dry air is 28.9647 g/mol. Multiplying $\ce{CO_2}$ expressed in μmol/mol by 44.01/28.9647=1.5194 comes rather close. A tricky detail is that some of that standard molecular mass of dry air includes a small contribution from $\ce{CO_2}$. After accounting for this I get a value close a bit over 1.5196. Rounding either value to three significant digits results in a conversion factor of 1.52.